# How to correctly decode a protobuf binary message in Python? ParseFromString returns me an int

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Currently I am dealing with a Protobuf project, and I need to first encode the protobuf structure in binary, and then decode it again. I need something to retrieve the original structure with the data, either in pb2 format or in a human readable string.

As a test, I have performed the following (simplified) code:

```
import coeff_pb2 as pb2

coeff = pb2.SHCoefficients() # SHCoefficients is the name of the structure
# Adding data to the structure
x = coeff.SerializeToString()
y = coeff.ParseFromString(x)
```

The x variable returns a binary message, as expected. However, y returns instead an int. What do I need to do?

EDIT
My proto file:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";
                
message SHCoefficients {
    uint32 week_nr = 1;
    double sow = 2;
    uint32 time_reference = 3;
    uint32 lmax = 4;
    uint32 n_coff = 5;
    repeated double clm = 6;
    repeated double slm = 7;
}
```

Comment: "However, y returns instead an int." What do you think it should be instead? Why?

Comment: A human-readable format, like the original protobuffer object, or a string

Answer (score 1):

`ParseFromString` returns an integer which is *the number of bytes read* and not the final decoded message. You should check the decoded message instead.

```py
import coeff_pb2 as pb2

x = pb2.SHCoefficients()
x_serialized = x.SerializeToString()

# Now deserialize it
y = pb2.SHCoefficients() # Init a new (empty) value
retval = y.ParseFromString(x_serialized) # Decode a Protobuf message from a string
print(y.lmax)  # Check a field from the decoded message, it will be zero
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ParseFromString`](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/message.html#google.protobuf.message.Message.MergeFromString) is a method that is applied to an instance of a Message.

In your code, you're serializing `coeff` to `x` and then deserializing `x` back into `coeff`.

You could do:

```
coeff2 = pb2.SHCoefficients()
coeff2.ParseFromString(x)
print(coeff2)
```

The Protocol Buffers Documentation includes a decent [tutorial](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/pythontutorial/) for Python.

###### Updated

```bash
# Create virtualenv
python3 -m venv venv

# Activate virtualenv
source venv/bin/activate

# Install current Protobuf
python3 -m pip install protobuf==4.22.1

# Generate Python and pyi file
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--python_out=${PWD} \
--pyi_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/coeff.proto
```

```py
import coeff_pb2 as pb2

# Create Messages
coeff1 = pb2.SHCoefficients()
coeff2 = pb2.SHCoefficients()

# Populate the first
coeff1.week_nr = 99
coeff1.sow = 99.99

# See Timestamp (below)
coeff1.time_reference = 99

coeff1.lmax = 99
coeff1.n_coff = 99

# Repeated: either append
coeff1.clm.append(99.99)
coeff1.clm.append(99.99)

# Repeated: or extend
coeff1.slm.extend([99.99,99.99])

# Print
print(coeff1)

# Serialize the first
b = coeff1.SerializeToString()

# Deserialize the serialized first message into the second
coeff2.ParseFromString(b)

# Print
print(coeff2)
```

Run:

```
week_nr: 99
sow: 99.99
time_reference: 99
lmax: 99
n_coff: 99
clm: 99.99
clm: 99.99
slm: 99.99
slm: 99.99

week_nr: 99
sow: 99.99
time_reference: 99
lmax: 99
n_coff: 99
clm: 99.99
clm: 99.99
slm: 99.99
slm: 99.99
```

> **NOTE** It's unclear from your proto. If `time_reference` is intended to reference a timestamp, consider using [Timestamp](https://protobuf.dev/reference/python/python-generated/#timestamp) Google's [Well-known Types](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/)

Comment: Unfortunately, it still gives me an integer

Comment: Please add your proto file to the question

Comment: Alright, added it

Comment: I'll update my answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you are using Python3? As per your example, I see you are using the protobuf2 (pb2) format. But if you are using python3, it won't work. I was facing the same issue. When using the `ParseFromString` method it returned an integer which was the length of the string read. Here is how you would do in python3.

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/protobuf3/

1. install protobuf3 - `pip install protobuf3`
2. generate .py file - `protoc --python3_out=<dest_dir> <source_file>.proto`
3. you would then use `parse_from_bytes` method to get reference to the decoded protobuf message (eg: https://pythonhosted.org/protobuf3/tutorial.html#the-protocol-buffer-api)

Hope that helps!